# Can you suggest a more reliable Wi-Fi setup for use on a Yacht?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have a friend with a yacht who is having networking issues trying to get devices connected on his boat. He regularly sails between marinas and needs to basically 'repeat' their Wi-fi connection.

However, most marinas only allow one device access at a time, and it's through their login screen before a connection is granted.

Here is his current setup:

- He has a Windows PC which connects via Wi-Fi to the marina's wi-fi connection
- From the LAN port, he connects the PC via a CAT5 cable to an Airport Extreme base station's WAN port
- The Airport Extreme then re-broadcasts the Wi-Fi signal to his other wireless devices
- He also has the onboard computer of the yacht connected in to the LAN port of the Airport Express, this allows him to control and monitor many aspects of the yacht via an iPhone/iPad

The problem with this setup is reliability. Often when he disconnects from the marina Wi-Fi network, and every time when he re-connects to a different marina or base station, the Airport Extreme wireless signal starts giving IP address conflicts and needs to be completely rebooted and reconfigured before it will start working again. Many marina networks are public, but have login screens which have to be overcome before a connection is granted.

He's using a combination of Windows and Apple devices.

I wondered if a router existed with two wireless aerials, one to connect to a wi-fi network and another to broadcast it again, that would act as a bridge. Then every device just connects to the single router. This sounds like a repeater but where it's creating a separate network so devices on that network can see each other (unlike through the marina wi-fi, where his iPhone couldn't see the yacht computer if it was using an ordinary repeater).

If you were to try and get around this, how would you do it differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like he's trying to use his AirPort base station as his DHCP server when he's at sea, but when he's in port, the Windows machine handling the Marina Wi-Fi connection must act as a NAT and DHCP server in order to share its Internet access, so the two DHCP servers conflict. If he left NAT enabled on the base station, it probably also complained of double NAT or even an IP subnet conflict.

The solution is to disable NAT and DHCP service on the base stations (make them act as transparent bridges between wireless clients and the wired Ethernet LAN), and leave it like that all the time, in port or at sea. Also keep the Windows box acting as the DHCP server at all times, so that client devices can still get IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a router with two wireless aerials. One aerial can be used for a hundred networks (though that many would probably be a bad idea).

You *can* get special routers that repeat a network but what you want is *not* a bridge.

If you have a DD-WRT or OpenWRT compatible router you can follow these sorts of guides:

https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=39077

Or you could buy a commercial repeater device:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dcomputers&field-keywords=wireless+repeater

They will however not work differently to your Airport Extreme, and will have the same problems - namely, you will have IP conflicts if you do not configure them correctly. Conversely, your Airport Extreme will do the job just fine as it is if you were to configure it correctly. You do not need different hardware:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202056

Comment: Thanks for your advice, could you point me to which specific part of the Apple support document gives the correct configuration? I would presume it was referencing this document: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204617 - but that document assumes you have configuration access to the primary base station, which in this case is owned and operated by the marina. Only the secondary station (the Airport Extreme onboard the yacht) is under our control.

Comment: It’s called radio, by the way. Most chips are limited to ~8 SSIDs.